# AJAX to show/hide div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

I want to implement a ajax call to a page every 3 seconds.
It will either return `0` if false or a html snippet like `<div>Content</div>`

How should I proceed to place or remove that div on the page according to what ajax returns ?

Comment: what you have tried ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **setInterval()**

```
setInterval(ajaxCall, 3000);

function ajaxCall() {
   $.ajax({url:url,
           type:'html',
           success:function(result){
             if(result==0)
               $('#content').hide();
              else
                $('#content').html(result).show();  

            }
        });
 }



 <div id="content">Content</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible way:

html

```
<div id="one" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="two" style="display:block"></div>
```

Now in your success function set the appropriate div visible or hidden

```
ajax.request
({
    // some code
    success: function(response)
    {
        // here check the answer and show the div with id one
        document.getElementById('one').style.display = 'block';
    }
})
```

Comment: I was considering doing that, although the div has a lot of images and 99% of the times it is to be hidden, so this is not the best alternative, performance wise.